# Docker: run python script that depends on mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, pymongo

I need to run this python script in docker:

```js
--mongodb_write_static.py--

import pymongo
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient('27017')
```

```
--in terminal--
docker-compose build #create Python env, no errors
docker-compose up #create Mongo env and run script
```

docker-compose up gives me:

- raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
  write_static_1  | pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 27017:27017: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Can someone help me please? Thanks a lot.

```js
--Dockerfile--

FROM python:3.8.3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code

RUN pip install datetime numpy pandas pymongo xlrd
CMD ["python", "mongodb_write_static.py"]
```

```js
--docker-compose.yml--

version: '3.8'
services:
  write_static:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - mongo
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    volumes:
      - .:/code
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    command: mongod --port 27017 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: What host is `MongoClient` supposed to connect to?  It looks like you've just given it a port number and not a host name.

Comment: To the Mongo database created in docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 1):

As the database and python code are running in different containers, MongoClient needs to understand which hostname to connect to. In your case you can tell it to connect to `mongo` because that is the name of the service. So your code change is just the line:

```
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient('mongo:27017')
```